# Automate Downloading Resources in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, hook, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I am building an application and it relies on static resource files. I was hoping to be able to find a way to download the resource files at a certain time in the workflow.

I have seen git-hooks and I have also seen GitLab runners etc. I have no preference I just want to be able to simply create automation of downloading resource files.

Comment: use ```wget``` or ```curl``` for downloading file over http from command line

Comment: I get that I am already using the `curl` command to do that, how do I commit and add it to my codebase. I understand creating the runner which I have it's just trying to get into my codebase which is the difficult part.

Answer (score 0):

My GitLab.cli ended up looking like the following:

I just had to generate a new private and public key to add to the repo and a few commands that I collected from looking at a bunch of different resources that can be found in the comments of the code.

```
#resources that I used
#https://forum.gitlab.com/t/is-it-possible-to-commit-artifacts-into-the-git/22218/7
#https://forum.gitlab.com/t/git-push-from-inside-a-gitlab-runner/30554/5
#https://marcosschroh.github.io/posts/autobumping-with-gitlab/
#https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor
#https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/
#https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#verifying-the-ssh-host-keys
#https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-skip-the-pipeline-from-job-gitlab/44947/2
#https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#skip-pipeline

build-job:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    ##
    ## Create the SSH directory and give it the right permissions
    ##
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh

    ##
    ## Install ssh-agent if not already installed, it is required by Docker.
    ## (change apt-get to yum if you use an RPM-based image)
    ##
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'


    # - ssh-keyscan $GITLAB_URL >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

    ##
    ## Run ssh-agent (inside the build environment)
    ##
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

    ##
    ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
    ## We're using tr to fix line endings which makes ed25519 keys work
    ## without extra base64 encoding.
    ## https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_48526556
    ##
    # - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    # - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add - > /dev/null


    - git config --global user.name "$CI_USERNAME"
    - git config --global user.email "$CI_EMAIL"
    - echo "$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

  script:
    # test out stuff from 
    # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/18106#note_12209180

    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"
    # for your information
    - whoami
    - printenv

    - git config --global user.name "${CI_USERNAME}"
    - git config --global user.email "${CI_EMAIL}"
    - git remote -v
    - git status
    # make your changes
    - touch test.txt
    - git add . 
    - git status
    - git remote -v
    # - git checkout master
    # - git merge ci_processing
    - git commit -m "Compiled PDF from $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA [skip ci]" || echo "No changes, nothing to commit!"
    - git remote rm origin && git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git
    - git push origin HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME # Pushes to the same branch as the trigger
    # push changes
    # always return true so that the build does not fail if there are no changes
    # - git push origin ci_processing:${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} || true
    # - git push origin ci_processing:${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
    # - git push origin ci_processing

# test-job1:
#   stage: test
#   script:
#     - echo "This job tests something"

# test-job2:
#   stage: test
#   script:
#     - echo "This job tests something, but takes more time than test-job1."
#     - echo "After the echo commands complete, it runs the sleep command for 20 seconds"
#     - echo "which simulates a test that runs 20 seconds longer than test-job1"
#     - sleep 20

# deploy-prod:
#   stage: deploy
#   script:
#     - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
```